# Retrieving the Name of a Document Saved in a Document Library Using the Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model, list-item

```
foreach (SPListItem item in listitems)
{
    String value = item.File.Name;    
}
```

The above sever side code shows how to retrieve the name of a document which is saved in a SharePoint document library by using `item.File.Name`. I have done this completely, but how do I do the same thing using the Client Object Model. What should I use instead of `item.File.Name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is the code you are looking for :

```
var fileName = '';  
var fileTitle = '';
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("LoadAction");
function LoadAction() 
{
GetFileDetails(fileID);

// File Title   
if(fileTitle != undefined)
    document.getElementById("txtTitle").innerHTML = fileTitle;
// File Name
if(fileName != undefined)
    document.getElementById("txtName").innerHTML = fileName;    
   }


function GetFileDetails(itemID)
{
    var temp_fileName = '';
    var temp_title ='';
    var query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>" + itemID + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: "Project Files",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />"+
                            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                        "</ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: query,
        async: false,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xData.responseText);
            //$(xmlDoc).find("z\\:row").each(function(){
            $(xmlDoc).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function(){
                temp_fileName = $(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef");
                temp_title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");    
            });
        }
    });

    fileName = temp_fileName == '' ? '': temp_fileName.split(';#')[1];
    fileTitle = temp_title; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use [`item.File.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.name.aspx). The difference being that this list item is a [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.aspx) type, and the `.File` here is [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.aspx).

If you're looking to learn more about how to use the CSOM, this should help get you started:

[How to: Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 client library code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179912.aspx)

Comment: thank you for your time and consideration, but i need to get the url of the particular document by using jquery. how would i ??

Comment: If you have another question, you should post it as a new thread. Please refer to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for further clarification.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.  (FYI, you will have to load the File and File.Name property but they can all be retrieved in the same call; e.g. `ctx.Load(items, i => i.Include(x => x.DisplayName, x => x.File, x => x.File.Name));`.)